# Install recaptcha gem with exsisting devise gem with rubymine 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What I've tried doing already: I've tried reading the documentation at github and getting it to work on Rubymine and I've managed to confuse myself with what is needed as far as controllers, and what is needed in the config folder. I've tried google and found some pretty good tutorials but their missing steps that I don't necessarily know to jump too.

What I'm trying to figure out: I want to be able use recaptcha in a login registration utlitizing the devise gem, I've already generated the pages for my devise login.

What I have so far:

I've installed and attached: devise 1.2.rc and recaptcha 0.3.1 I'm running Rubymine on windows xp. Ruby SDK 1.8.7-p302, with Rails 3.0.3

I've been to google and have my public and private keys
The next step tells me I'm supposed to add my keys to **project/config/initializers/recaptcha.rb** This is what is contained in that file:

```
 Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key = 'myKey'
  config.private_key = 'myKey'
 end
```

Now I'm supposed to fix up my **gemfile** with:

```
 gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
```

I also have my **config/application.rb** reading:

```
 require 'rails/all'
 require 'net/http'
```

I've also added to my **External Libraries/[gem] devise/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb** the recaptcha tag:

```
   <%= recaptcha_tags %>
   <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
```

Where I am running into issues (I think) is the 
**app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb** and the **config/routes.rb**

I'm kinda of at a loss for what exactly goes into these files. Any help would be appreciated or a tutorial someone has written that walks me through this step by step would be very helpful. Thanks

Here's what I have done after Felix's post:

**external libraries/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb**

class Devise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
        def create

```
      if verify_recaptcha then
          super
      else
          build_resource
          clean_up_passwords(resource)
          flash[:notice] = 'Invalid Captcha'
          render_with_scope :new
      end

  build_resource

  if resource.save
    if resource.active?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up
      sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => resource.inactive_message.to_s
      expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
      redirect_to after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    render_with_scope :new
  end
end
```

From **Project/config/routes.rb:**

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
```

This is the error that its spitting out:

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant RegistrationsController):

Rendered C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.0ms)   ..... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your routes, you can keep your normal devise routes except specifying your custom controller:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
```

In the registrations_controller.rb, you want to subclass the Devise RegistrationsController and override the 'create' method:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
        if verify_recaptcha then
            super
        else
            build_resource
            clean_up_passwords(resource)
            flash[:notice] = 'Invalid Captcha'
            render_with_scope :new
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: so in my registrations_controller.rb I have my current def create...I'm to replace completely or add to?

Comment: Well, your current registrations controller should be subclassing the Devise registrations controller and be empty otherwise unless you have made other customizations. If you already have a create method defined, you just want to stop the registration process if `verify_recaptcha` returns false.